# fonts.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in laravel

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, font-awesome, webfonts

I have an error loading the font awesome icons (not shown) in my project with the laravel framework, inside the css folder I have two backend_css folders where I wait for all css styles and in the other frontend_css folder I have it empty, the problem is that it doesn't load the awesome font icons version 5.2.0 in my template.

[image]

It seems that I have the wrong directory at the time of calling the fonts.min.css file, eh checked and I still can't find the error. help xf

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
urls:['/css/backend_css/fonts.min.css']
```

It's a good practice always use absolute path.

Post your code instead of screenshot so that others can copy your code and check it.